# Displaying images from firebase to flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Please I will like to know how I can display images stored in firebase to my flutter app using the list view. Please just a little description on how to proceed please. For example, bakery products images  to be displayed from firebase to my bakery app with prices. Any help please

Comment: https://github.com/ptyagicodecamp/flutter_cookbook/blob/widgets/flutter_widgets/lib/images/load_image.dart

Comment: here is the sample code

Comment: Thanks I will implement it.

Answer (score 1):

to get the url of a specific image :

```
final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('nameofimage');
// no need of the file extension, just the name does the job
var url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
print(url);
```

when you have the URL you can use it:

```
Image.network(url);
```

Comment: Hello, if I have many images which I want to display  them in a listview can this go?

Comment: This should work. Just save the name of the image with the other information that are going to be loaded as well.